# Create plot with 2 scales on x axis (both corresponding to same y axis datapoint)

Tags: r

I am trying create a plot with two x axis scales. The data all corresponds to the same y axis value, but is in two scales (mm and % on the x axis). As in attached picture.

How can this be achieved?

[image]

Thanks in advance,
Am

As above. I have tried sec.axis and x.continuous, but not sure they are right to use here.

I have attempted as above, but with no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in base R by adding in the axes manually using `axis()`. Here is a simple example:

```
plot(dpois(0:100, 10), type = "l", 
     axes = FALSE, xlab = "", ylab = "")
lines(dnbinom(0:100, mu = 20, size = 10))
axis(1, at = seq(0, 100, 10)) #first x axis
axis(1, at = seq(0, 100, 10), padj = 2) # second x axis
axis(2) # y axis
mtext(c("Value", "Density"), 1:2, padj = c(5.5, -4)) # axis labels
mtext(c("Axis 1", "Axis 2"), 1, adj = -0.2, padj = c(1.5, 3.5)) # additional labels
```

The `padj` call is "parallel adjust" and moves the axis down a bit (here, by two lines).

[image]